# How to find your Stardew Valley invite code?

Tags: stardew-valley

I want to play online multiplayer on steam with my girlfriend, but can't find the invite code. Where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The invite code is given to you by the person hosting the game.

Once the host has the game set up, the invite code can be found in the options menu, under the Multiplayer submenu:

[image: Screenshot of Stardew Valley's option menu]

If you're friends on Steam with the host, you don't even need to enter a code if the host has the game open for friends, like in the picture above (which is the default).

Comment: You need to be online on steam, speaking from experience...

Comment: If you're on Linux and bought the game from GOG - you won't see the "Show Invite Code" option. You need at least GOG Galaxy, which is not available on Linux ATM. Your best bet would probably be Hamachi + LAN